# Encountered a problem with a smaller integral within the bigger double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The question states to solve the following equation by transforming to polar coordinates.$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^{2}+y^{2})} \ dx \ dy$$

So far I have managed to put the equation into polar form and change the limits, as well as multiplying by the Jacobian, which in this case is simply $r$, but for the life of me I can't seem to progress past this stage.

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} r \ dr \ d\theta$$

It was my understanding that the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} dr$ had no solutions but clearly it does otherwise the question would be fairly redundant. Perhaps my brain has started to melt as finals draw to a close, perhaps I am missing something trivial. Either way, I am in need of help and would be grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: The $\theta$ variable is independent, so it just gives you a $2\pi$.  For the $r$ variable, use the $u$-substitution $u=r^2$.  $\int_0^xe^{-r^2}dr$ does not have a closed form in terms of elementary functions, but it does exist (even though you can't write it down simply).

Comment: You have to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}r\mathrm{d}r$, not $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}\mathrm{d}r$.

Comment: Thank you both very much. It would seem that, despite accounting for the Jacobian in my transformation, I didn't actually use it in my integral. @Mathematician42, you are very wise, indeed.

Comment: @Overclock So... is this question answered for you?

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes. I realised my error and have solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at this solution
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta \qquad (\text{Jacobian})\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdr \\
&=\theta\big|_{0}^{2\pi}\big(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-r^2}\big|_{0}^{\infty}\big)\\
&=2\pi\biggl(\frac{1}{2}\biggl)\\
&=\pi
\end{align*}